# Set a Virtual Page View with Universal GA

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

This is my HTML from. and i'm trying to set a Virtual Page View when submitting the form but i just can't make it work.
Pls advice

```
                    <form id="frmContact" action="post.php" method="post">  

                    <div class="form-right-pnl">
                        <input type="text" class="required name" size="40" placeholder="×©× ×ž×œ×:" name="full_name">
                        <input type="text" class="required phone" size="40" placeholder="×˜×œ×¤×•×Ÿ:" name="phone">
                        <input type="text" class="required email" size="40" placeholder='×“×•×"×œ:' name="email">
                        <span>×ž××©×¨ ×§×‘×œ×ª ×—×•×ž×¨×™× ×¤×¨×¡×•×ž×™×™×</span> 
                        <input type="checkbox" class="radio_btn" name="selling_a_property" checked value="Yes"/> 
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-left-pnl" id='basic-modal'>

                        <input class="ddl_list" type="submit" value="" onClick=”_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘Forms’, ‘Submit’]);” />
                    </div>      
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Can you clarify ? The title asks for a virtual pageview, but the inline code is actually for event tracking which is a different thing. Also we would need to know what version of the tracking code you use (your inline code is for an older version of the tracking code and will not work along with the current version).

Comment: So i guess my problem is bigger the i thought :) I need to create a VPV on submit when using Universal Analytics. Thanks!

Comment: A virtual pageview shows up in the behavior reports under "All pages" ("virtual" meaning that is is recorded like any other page despite the fact that it does not physically exists on your server).  An event shows up in the behavior reports under "Events" ("Top events", "Event Urls and several other reports). Which one is the ony you need (it would seem that an event is more appropriate) ?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
<input class="ddl_list" type="submit" value="" onClick=”_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘Forms’, ‘Submit’]);” />
```

for

```
<input class="ddl_list" type="submit" value="" onClick=”_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/virtual-page-view-on-click-submit-button']);” />
```